# How to draw different polylines

Tags: java, android, maps, polyline

i'm working on a Android App in which i draw polylines, the thing is that i need to draw different "routes" depending on which option the user selects, like for example: if they choose "a" a route will be drawn, and if the choose "b" another route will be drawn.

I've already draw a route in my project, but don't know how to draw different routes depending on which option was choosen.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Couldnt u add different polylines for different routes?

Comment: @anoo_radha yeap